# How do I view the content of the Clipboard in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, clipboard

I'm looking to visually view the contents of my clipboard in Windows 8.  From what I've researched the Clipboard viewer program is only installed in Windows XP and below.

Is there another way to view the contents of the Clipboard visually within Windows 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **[Save.me](http://www.aiclipboard.com/)**

A Clipboard Manager For Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8. It automatically saves everything you are working on, including text, images, URLs, files, and folders. It lets you manage the clipboard entries, letting you add new items, edit them, save them in files and delete the unneeded ones. You can even preview any saved clipboard item from right within the app.
Save.me is a portable application and can be launched directly from your computer or even a USB flash drive. Once started, it runs in the system tray and saves everything you copy to the clipboard.

*Example Screenshot:*

[image]

**Edit**

Alternatively you may be in interested in an Application called:

[Keeeb](http://keeeb.com/)

Dubbed **"The Next Generation Content Curation"** - Offers A Softboard For Bookmarking & Organizing Web Clippings and boasts a special import function that allows users a smooth transition from Clipboard by migrating their existing clips.

A review of it was carried out recently [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/web/keeeb-offers-softboard-for-bookmarking-organizing-web-clippings/).

Comment: Wow, exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 4):

True. There is no Clipboard viewer application included in Windows 8. Try a free application like [Free Clipboard Viewer](http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/).

I have just learned from Wikipedia that it is possible to copy the executable from Windows XP and use it in Windows Vista, 7 and 8. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClipBook_Viewer) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do not have a exe (clipbrd.exe) or windows xp, just Windows 7 & 8.

Comment: FYI The XP executable does **not** work on Windows 10

Answer (score -1):

My advice is to download a third party app as [clipclip.com](http://www.clipclip.com)

So you can view your clipboard history, plus saving and organizing your clips.